# Комбинации чисел из разных списков

Tags: python

Как составить все комбинации цифр, имея, например, 2 списка и беря только по одному числу из каждого?
И что бы это работало на больших размерах.

```
a = [1,2]
b = [4,5]
result = [14, 41, 15, 51, 24, 42, 25, 52]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

result = reduce(add, [[10*x + y, 10*y + x] for x in a for y in b])
```

Comment: Элегантно :) Без импортов: `result = sum([[10*x + y, 10*y + x] for x in a for y in b], [])`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, еще элегантнее, спасибо!

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, напишите ваше решение как ответ и я буду голосовать за.

Answer (score 0):

Простой вариант через циклы:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [4, 5]

result = []

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        result += [i * 10 + j, j * 10 + i]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [10*x + y for x in a for y in b] + [10*x + y for x in b for y in a]
```

Результат:

> ```
> [14, 15, 24, 25, 41, 42, 51, 52]
> ```